# Selecting top(n) 2 Related Tables Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Here's my entity datasource

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourceCLient" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="name=MBSDbEntities" DefaultContainerName="MBSDbEntities"
        EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="ReservationLists" Include="UserProfile" OrderBy="it.Date" Where="">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Here's my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceCLient">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserProfile.FirstMidname">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserProfile.FirstMidname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserProfile.FirstMidname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TransactionType" HeaderText="TransactionType" 
                SortExpression="TransactionType" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                SortExpression="Status" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

I can display 2 Related Tables but I can't display with specific number of it. Can you guys help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you add in some code you have tried?

Comment: Could you please name your tables like "Users", "Rooms" some meaning names! , post your code & error.

Comment: i'm not coding it, i'm using entity datasource and configuring it on Properties

Comment: I don't know how to take only a specific number of data. example I just want to display only 5 datas of it

Comment: @LukeMcGregor bro there's an update in my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the table and then Order them by your field *(probably TestDate)* and later use [Enumerable.Take()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) to take top `5` records. Something like

```
var query = (from q in table1 
            join r  in table2 on q.UserID equals r.UserID)
            .OrderBy(s=> s.TestDate)
            .Take(5);
```

Comment: can i do it only in entity datasource properties? and how thanks

Comment: What do you mean by properties ?

Comment: Visual Studio. The properties of EntityDatasource there is a properties of it right? where it can be configured easily i can display 2 related tables but i don't know how to display it when taking only 5 of it

Comment: @CarloAdap, I can't really get what you meant in your comments, could you be precise

Comment: I don't know how to take only a specific number of data. example I just want to display only 5 datas of it

Comment: still there? Still hoping you can help me

Comment: @CarloAdap, just saw your updated question, I am afraid you can't use `Take` with EntityDataSource, instead you can get the data using the above query in code behind and then bind the result with datagrid.